# USB compatible with Topping VX1 USB DAC Amp?

Tags: usb, audio-playback

Is the Raspberry Pi B compatible with a USB DAC mini amp such as the Topping VX1?

According to the Topping VX1 specs, it has:
DAC: USB Controller by Burr-Brown PCM2704
Tripaths TA2024B chipset

I have a Topping VX1 which I am using with a macbook via USB cable, and I would like to know if it would be compatible with the Raspberry Pi B. Is it plug & play, or is some configuration/setup required?

---

Edit: I guess I will have to just try it out myself :)  The Pi 2 should be arriving soon.

Comment: Once you try it, please consider answering your own question to help others who may have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Topping VX1 USB DAC mini amp is plug and play compatible with the Raspberry Pi B running Volumio v 1.55.

"VX1" appears on the Playback MPD Configuration - Audio Output menu.
Sound quality is very good.